# Как убрать задний фон у кнопки, но оставить границу?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qpushbutton

Возникла проблема, мне нужно убрать задний фон у кнопки.

Я использовал метод `setFlat(True)`, но он скрывает и границу, можно ли оставить границу, желательно граница с пунктиром.

Задний фон не однородный например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bott = QPushButton(self)
        self.bott.setText("push")
        self.bott.move(10, 10)
        self.bott.setFlat(True)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Какой есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой **`нужно получить`**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну или хотя бы обычную границу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте StyleSheet:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, qApp
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QLineEdit, QRadioButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QFileDialog


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.bott = QPushButton(self)
        self.bott.setText("push")
        self.bott.move(10, 10)
        self.bott.setFlat(True)
        
        self.bott.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: transparent; 
                border-radius: 5px;
                border: 2px dashed red;
            }
            QPushButton:hover:pressed {
                background-color: #FF6B6B;
                color: #fff;    
                border: 2px solid #11052C;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #0ff;
                border: 2px solid #FFA6D5;
            }
        """) 
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]